# Can I use Xen virtualization/paravirtualization when my processor doesn't support VTX?

Tags: virtualization, xen

I have a server (4 GB RAM, 64-Bit Intel Atom 330 1.6 GHz processor).

The processor doesn't support any kind of virtualization (I looked up the documentation).

Can I still use Xen to make several servers out of it, using virtualization or paravirtualization?

If yes, please also name whether it's virtualization or paravirtualization that's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use Xen.

But you can only use paravirtualization, so that you need a modified guest OS.

Modified Windows guest suitable for paravirtualization are not available, so you can only use Linux guests.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one version of Windows that has been modified by microsoft that supports the paravirtualization with Xen,it's xp. but you will not be able to find a copy of it.

Comment: So how do you know this to be true :)

Comment: @mario: Wrong, there is one on thepiratebay.se :)